# Sidebar with two flexbox navs top and bottom

Tags: css, flexbox

I´m trying to align two navigations inside a sidebar –with 100% viewport height – by use of flexbox.

- the red box should be placed on the top of it´s sidebar parent
- the blue box on the bottom.

In case the red navigation grows and the space between both is to little the sidebar should be scrollable in y-axis. What I´ve tried is setting top and bottom margin for both without luck. Can somebody help me out ?

Thanks!

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.sidebar__top {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.sidebar__bottom {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar">
  <nav class="sidebar__top"></nav>
  <nav class="sidebar__bottom"></nav>
</aside>
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1dw7h2sp/1/

Comment: So you also want the red box to be filling out the remaining space, or is it ok if there is some gray gap?

Comment: Hi lumio, it´s okay if red fills the gap ;)

Comment: Even if not, removing `flex-grow` should do the trick (as described in my answer) :)

Comment: Great thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably other ways to do this. In short I did the following:

1. Wrap your elements with a parent that is able to grow in size (`.sidebar__wrapper`)
2. Set the `min-height` instead of `height` so it can grow
3. Use `flex-grow` if you want an element to fill out the remaining space.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* set up a wrapper that can grow in size */
.sidebar__wrapper {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #808080;
  
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.sidebar__top {
  background: red;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  
  /* this fills up the remaining space */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.sidebar__bottom {
  background: blue;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar__wrapper">
    <nav class="sidebar__top" contenteditable="true">
      <p>test</p>
    </nav>
    <nav class="sidebar__bottom"></nav>
  </div>
</aside>
```